# Google Chrome headless remote debugging no response on /json url

Tags: google-chrome, jasmine, google-chrome-devtools, semaphore-ci

I try to fix some old ruby app. But I have an issue with selenium tests. I debug gems and found out that test runners start the Google Chrome with that options:
`path\to\chrome --headless --no-sandbox --remote-debugging-port=9222` then waits a moment and sends a get request to `localhost:9222/json`.
When the test worked, the response to the above request was not empty, but now I got only `[   ]`.

The tests are triggered in SemaphoreCI on ubuntu with the latest Google Chrome and Google Chrome driver. Any idea what may be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Chrome 111 it is required to add

```
--remote-allow-origins=*
```

as a parameter.

Comment: It did not help. I found that I need add `about:blank` argument in command to start chrome. I guess this is a breaking change,  but I did not found nothing else

Comment: Holy cow, you saved the day. To summarize for anybody who is having "No inspectable targets" errors with recent Chrome / Chromium running in headless mode, but not experiencing it in "normal" interactive mode - Chrome(ium) did a breaking change recently, and when started headless, it seems it has somehow "zero" tabs open. No tab, nothing to remotely control and the instatiation of e.g. a "chrome-remote-interface" object fails constantly with this error. Solution: as you wrote above, the command line needs an url, and `about:blank` is a short and failsafe way to provide one. Thanks !!!

Comment: Note, without `--remote-allow-origins=*`, chrome will return 403 even Origin header is localhost.

Answer (score 1):

You should send a get request to `http://localhost:9222/json/version`

Answer (score 0):

As user3493916 stated in his comment, adding a target URL (e.g. `about:blank`) when starting Chrome/Chromium helps to fix the issue.